# Ionic and Capacitor: How can i change the capacitor.config.ts file to a capacitor.config.json file?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, config, capacitor

I created an Angular/Ionic project with capacitor. Now I wanted to make changes in my capacitor.config.json but this file is missing? Instead there is the capacitor.config.ts?!

I need the JSON File because otherwise a specific plugin doesnt work!

Here are pictures of my directory and my package.json:
[Directory and Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG59X.png)

[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmsiA.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capacitor 3 allows to have .json, .js or .ts config file.

`npx cap init` command will create a .ts file if typescript is installed
If you don’t want a .ts file you can just remove it and create a .json file, but everything should still work no matter what the config file extension is.

Answer (score 0):

The version I'm using has the file you require.
[application files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ceO.png)
[ionic version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeGKj.png)

Please try out ionic 6.18.1 version if possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).